# "Undefined variable" Search functionality

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to set search functionality for the table that fetches and holds data from the database. Currently, my table can view data from the database but cannot search.
Below is my table which that displays data

```
<table class="table">
                    <thead class=" text-primary">
                        <th>
                            Brand Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Phone
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Reg No.
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Certificate
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Email
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            User-Role
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Edit
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Delete
                        </th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($user as $receiver)
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{$receiver->name}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{$receiver->phone}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{$receiver->regno}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{$receiver->certificate}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{$receiver->email}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{$receiver->usertype}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/org-edit/{{$receiver->id}}" class="btn btn-success">EDIT</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form class = "delete" action="org-delete/{{$receiver->id}}" method="post">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                                    <button class="delete btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach

                        <script>
                            $(".delete").on("submit", function(){
                                return confirm("Are you sure?");
                            });
                        </script>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And the form i use to search query.

```
<form action="{{ url('searchorg')}}" method="post">
{{csrf_field()}}
{{method_field('PUT')}}
<div class="input-group no-border">
    <input type="text" name="q1" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="now-ui-icons ui-1_zoom-bold"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller "OrganizationController.php"

```
    public function search(Request $request)
{
   if($q = Input::get ( 'q1' )){
    $user1 = User::where('name','LIKE','%'.$q1.'%')->orWhere('email','LIKE','%'.$q1.'%')->orWhere('phone','LIKE','%'.$q1.'%')->orWhere('usertype','LIKE','%'.$q1.'%')->orWhere('regno','LIKE','%'.$q1.'%')->orWhere('lat','LIKE','%'.$q1.'%')->orWhere('long','LIKE','%'.$q1.'%')->get();
    if(count($user1) > 0)
        return view('admin.register')->withDetails('user',$user1)->withQuery ($q);
    else return view ('admin.register')->withMessage('No Details found. Try to search again !');
}else{ 
    $user = User::where('usertype', 'organization')->get();
    return view('admin/organization.organizations')->with('user',$user);
}
}
```

And the Route

```
Route::any('/searchorg','Admin\OrganizationController@search');
```

Whenever I search something on the search form, it brings error "undefined variable: q1".

I will appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: `q1` undefine because you have assigned in `$q`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a change in the controller:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q1 = Input::get( 'q1' );

    if( !empty( $q1 ) ) {

        $user1 = User::where('name','LIKE','%'.$q1.'%')->orWhere('email','LIKE','%'.$q1.'%')->orWhere('phone','LIKE','%'.$q1.'%')->orWhere('usertype','LIKE','%'.$q1.'%')->orWhere('regno','LIKE','%'.$q1.'%')->orWhere('lat','LIKE','%'.$q1.'%')->orWhere('long','LIKE','%'.$q1.'%')->get();
        if(count($user1) > 0){
            return view('admin.register')->withDetails('user',$user1);
        } else { 
            return view ('admin.register')->withMessage('No Details found. Try to search again !');
        }
    } else { 
        $user = User::where('usertype', 'organization')->get();
        return view('admin/organization.organizations')->with('user',$user);
    }
}
```